# Copying selected files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a Python script to copy files with the extension '.txt' from one folder to another folder. I am typing the following on the command line:

```
python C:/Users/Username/Desktop/folder_name/copyselect.py C:/Users/Username/Desktop/folder_name C:Users/Username/Desktop/new_folder
```

This is the code:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil

def main():
  src = sys.argv[1]
  dst = sys.argv[2]

  for filenames, dirpath, dirnames in os.walk(src):
    if not os.path.isdir(dst):
      os.makedirs(dst)
    for filename in filenames:
      if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(src, filename), dst)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I keep receiving the following error message:

```
IO Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Username/Desktop/folder_name/C'
```

Why is this mysterious 'C' appearing following 'folder_name'? It appears to be coming from the 'C' in the last filepath in the command line. Is this a Windows thing? How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 1):

You got the order of results from [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) reversed. Should be:

```
  for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src):
    if not os.path.isdir(dst):
      os.makedirs(dst)
    for filename in filenames:
      if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(src, filename), dst)
```

**And** you are missing a slash on your second argument. 
Should be:

`python "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/folder_name/copyselect.py" "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/folder_name" "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/new_folder"`

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Put your command arguments between single quotes ...

```
python C:/Users/Username/Desktop/folder_name/copyselect.py 'C:/Users/Username/Desktop/folder_name' 'C:Users/Username/Desktop/new_folder'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Copy the files with Two examples.
#If your are not expecting this answer, sorry.

#...................................................................
import os, shutil
src = os.path.abspath (sys.argv[1])
dst = os.path.abspath (sys.argv[2])

for filenames, dirpath, dirnames in os.walk(src):

    dstRoot     = dst + filenames.replace (src, '')

    if not os.path.isdir (dstRoot):
        os.makedirs (dstRoot)

    for dirname in dirnames:
        if dirname.endswith('.txt'):
            sourceDocu  = (filenames + '\\' + dirname)
            targetDocu  = (dstRoot + '\\' + dirname)            
            shutil.copy2 (sourceDocu, targetDocu)

#...................................................................
#Files copy from Single folder
import os, shutil
src = os.path.abspath (sys.argv[1])
dst = os.path.abspath (sys.argv[2])

fileList    = os.listdir (src)

if fileList :
    if not os.path.isdir (dst):
        os.makedirs (dst)

    for eachFile in fileList :        
         if eachFile.endswith('.txt') :             
            shutil.copy2 (src + '\\' + eachFile, dst + '\\' + eachFile)            

 #...................................................................
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers!

After making these edits, the script runs if I add in filepaths for **src** and **dst**, but I can't get it to run from the command line.

Since I'd like the script to search subfolders, so I added a line in to handle that. The script now looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil

def main():
  src = sys.argv[1]
  dst = sys.argv[2]

  for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src):
    if not os.path.isdir(dst):
      os.makedirs(dst)
    filenames = [os.path.join(dirpath, filename) for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src) for filename in filenames]
    for filename in filenames:
      if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(src, filename), dst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

At the command line, I'm typing this:

```
python C:/Users/Username/Desktop/folder_name/copyselect.py 'C:/Users/Username/Desktop/folder_name' 'C:/Users/Username/Desktop/new_folder'
```

Does anyone know what the error is that is preventing this script from running at the command line? Thanks.